# How is the horizon size related to the Hubble parameter or number of e folds of inflation?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

I know the following relations $$N=\int_{t_i}^{t_f}Hdt\\ r_{hor}=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{dt}{a(t)}$$
where N is the number of e folds and $r_{hor}$ is the comoving horizon size. Comoving horizon is related to the physical size of the horizon as following:$$d_{hor}(a_*)=a_* r_{hor}(a_*)$$

Comment: Make sure to define what you mean by $a_*$.

Comment: no I already know that of course, and the definition of $a_*$ doesn't help  much with what i want (its the value of scale factor in the comoving frame) to the answer, I just need the relation between $r_{hor}$. I am asked to find the number of e-folds of inflation for the current horizon size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, the *comoving* horizon of an observer at time $t$ is

$$
r_h(t) = \int_0^t\frac{{\rm d}ct}{a(t)} = \int_0^a \frac{{\rm d}a}{a}\left[\frac{8\pi G \rho a^2}{3c^2} - K\right]^{-1/2} \label{1}\tag{1}
$$

where I have used the [first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) Friedmann equation. The problem with this expression it that is finite at early times $a\to 0$, when radiation dominates the density $\rho \sim a^{-4}$, this of course is at odds with the idea of a universe at thermal equilibrium.

To solve this problem, imagine that at early times the density behaves as $\rho \sim a^{-\beta}$ with $\beta < 2$, which clearly makes Eq. $\ref{1}$ diverge. When you plug in this into the first law of thermodynamics

$$
\frac{{\rm d} \rho}{{\rm d}a} + 3\left(\frac{\rho + P/c^2}{a} \right) = 0 \label{2}\tag{2}
$$

you can conclude that

$$
\rho + 3 P/c^2 <0 \label{3}\tag{3}
$$

which together with the second Friedmann equation leads to the requirement

$$
\ddot{a} > 0 \label{4}\tag{4}
$$

Eq. $\ref{4}$ is then an accelerated universe dominated by a component that satisfies Eq. $\ref{3}$. An example of such component is vacuum energy

$$
P = -\rho c^2 \label{5}\tag{5}
$$

In this case, the scale factor is simply

$$
a(t) \sim e^{H t} ~~~\mbox{with}~~~ H^2 = \frac{8\pi G \rho}{3}
$$

The question now is then how large this number must be to solve the problem with $r_h$? This is easy to figure out if you consider two length scales at the time of last scattering

> Going forward

The size of the horizon during this epoch dominated by Eq. $\ref{5}$ is simply

$$
r_h^{\rm forward} = \int_{t_i}^{t_{ls}}\frac{{\rm d}ct}{a(t)} = \frac{e^{H\Delta t}-1}{a(t_e)H}
$$

> Going backward

The size of the horizon at the time of last scattering as seen from today is

$$
r_h^{\rm backward} = \int_{t_{ls}}^{t_0}\frac{{\rm d}ct}{a(t)} \approx 3t_0
$$

If the universe is to be in thermal equilibrium then

$$
r_h^{\rm forward}(t_{ls}) > r_h^{\rm backward}(t_{ls})
$$

which leads to

$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]
{
e^{H \Delta t} > 3 H a(t_e)t_0 \sim 10^{25}
}
$$

And from there you can get number of $e$-foldings of $a$ during the inflationary epoch.

Comment: Could you please, explain why that condition is required in order to have thermal equilibrium?

Comment: @alexsanchezcast A divergent horizon, implies that every observer is causally connected with every other observer, hence allowing thermal equilibrium